# Create text file in memory and upload to azure blob storage using python

Tags: azure, io, azure-blob-storage

So I want to create a python function that creates an inmemory text file that I can pass a string, or multiple strings to and upload to azure blob storage. Doing it with a normal text file is a novel task, but I can't seem to get it happen using the io module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out this https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/ which given in detail upload a file to azure blob storage by doing the following.

You can easily pass the string to `upload_blob` method using python as below:

```py
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<connection_string>", container_name="my_container", blob_name="my_blob")

data = "test"
blob.upload_blob(data)
```

Comment: how can upload a large file to blob when file is not fit in memory